# How to remove empty fields from mongoDB while adding a document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to remove Languages from the document if it's empty.

```
  const departmentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  Depart: { type: String, required: true, minlength: 5, maxlength: 50 },
  Languages: [languageSchema]
});
```

[image]

I already tried `Languages: { type: [languageSchema], required: false }` but no luck.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution myself as always :p

```
const departmentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  Depart: { type: String, required: true, minlength: 5, maxlength: 50 },
  Languages: [languageSchema]
});

departmentSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  if (this.isNew && 0 === this.Languages.length) {
    this.Languages= undefined;                                                                                                                                   
  }
  next();
})
```

This will do the trick. ^

Answer (score -1):

set `minimize` option to false, and if there are any empty objects mongoose will delete this field, or try to set the value to `undefined`

```
const departmentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  Depart: { type: String, required: true, minlength: 5, maxlength: 50 },
  Languages: [languageSchema],
  { minimize: false }
});
```

Or you can check on front app if there are any language add `language` value

```
const data;
if(departament.languages.length > 0) {
  data.language = departament.languages;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan for replying

according to the docs { minimize: true } removes empty object but it doesn't work for me :( 

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#minimize

Comment: did you tried to set value to undefined ? or do this filter on front application how I showed above

Comment: sorry but I didn't get your second solution.. :(

Comment: if you meant front end then I don't have any front end yet... I am working on back end only...

Comment: Mongoose will, by default, "minimize" schemas by removing empty objects. This behavior can be overridden by setting minimize option to false. It will then store empty objects. Your first answer is the other way around